# Can't center old reCaptcha code

Tags: javascript, html, css, captcha

I'm using an old code from reCaptcha and i'm trying to center it in a form but it's not working.

What i tried:

```
margin:0 auto;
margin:0 auto !important;
text-align:center;
```

HTML:

```
<p class="captcha">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var RecaptchaOptions = {
        lang : 'en',
        theme : 'white',
        tabindex : 9
        };
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.recaptcha.net/challenge?k=..."></script>
<noscript>
    <iframe src="http://api.recaptcha.net/noscript?k=..." height="300" width="500"></iframe><br/>
    <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge"/>
</noscript>
    <span class="validation-error"></span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using:

```
text-align:center;
```

On a form element does not work, browsers nevver implemented that feature. What you need to do is wrap a div around the CAPTCHA like so:

```
<div align=center><CAPTCHA></div>
```

Comment: Ok, it works but it's not HTML5 valid, that's because i tried text-align.